# Cannot append to a file: Append replaces the content

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

The following command does not append but replaces the content

```
echo 0 >> /sys/block/nvme0n1/queue/nomerges
```

I don't want to replace but append. But I'm curious Is there something special about this file?

It also doesn't allow more than one character as its input.

Comment: Most files in /sys have something special about them.

Answer (score 2):

Look at https://serverfault.com/questions/865787/what-does-the-nomerge-mean-in-linux-system

It might help you in understanding, that there are only 3 options that the file can take.

Also:
nomerges enables the user to disable the lookup logic involved with IO
merging requests in the block layer. By default (0) all merges are
enabled. When set to 1 only simple one-hit merges will be tried. When
set to 2 no merge algorithms will be tried (including one-hit or more
complex tree/hash lookups).

Comment: My main question is how is kernel enforcing those value restriction. Is there a way to set such restrictions for user generated files?